# Assign each cell to the list of users

Tags: excel, vba

Might sound silly but I would like to ask for an advice on how to achieve this.

I have 2 sheets in my Excel.

Sheet 1 is where I place my users.
Sheet 2 is where I place something else.

So it's like this

[image]

I want to actually assign all those place to each users respectively.

Any idea or just an advice on how to achieve this.

Note*** I'm not asking for the code but if you'll provide even if the idea much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Build a Pivot table based on data in Sheet2.

Comment: Formula like this will work if you are looking to assign each users a place respectively ,  `=INDEX(Sheet'!1$A$2:$A$3,MOD((ROW()-2),2)+1)`

Comment: Maybe `=LET(DataSet1,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7, DataSet2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$3, Count1,COUNTA(DataSet1), Count2,COUNTA(DataSet2), Group1,INDEX(DataSet1,INT(SEQUENCE(Count1*Count2,,1,1/Count2))), Group2,INDEX(DataSet2,MOD(SEQUENCE(Count1*Count2,,0),Count2)+1), SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},Group1,Group2)))`